# Web Application fails to start on remote tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, java-ee-7

I have application running on tomcat7. In my IDE (Eclipse) I can easily deploy it to tomcat and run and everything works fine however when I make mvn clean install and copy paste ROOT.war artifact to another tomcat, application fails to start with following error:

```
Feb 12, 2015 1:20:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer@d5e80cc]
Feb 12, 2015 1:20:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 12, 2015 1:20:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.su4ssspport.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:194)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5542)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1877)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Feb 12, 2015 1:20:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 12, 2015 1:20:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 12, 2015 1:20:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 12, 2015 1:20:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@19f1f128')
```

How can I solve it?

PS
tomcat installed on Windows machine

Comment: Does your project in Eclipse follows the standard Maven web app layout?http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html.

Comment: Its web app but it also has pom.xml

Comment: I am aware it's a Webapp and that as a Maven project will have a pom.xml. What I was asking was: have you checked that the directory structure of your project matches the Maven standard WebApp layout as detailed in the previous link?

Comment: Yes I did. Project has WebApp layout

Comment: I would begin by unzipping the WAR and ensuring that all expected resources are there.